# Ruby - Return record with longest string in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just need the record with the longest string in the `product_description` column.

A record could have `nil` in the `product_description` column

Which is why this won't work:

```
Product.where(parent_product_id: 22033).pluck(:product_description).max_by(&:length)
```

Then I try SQL and get:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference (Query method called with non-attribute argument(s): "max(length(product_description))")
```

From this query:

```
Product.where(parent_product_id: 22033).pluck("max(length(product_description))")
```

This returns the same:

```
Product.where(parent_product_id: 22033).order("MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(product_description)) desc").limit(1)
```

But `product_description` is definitely a column on the `Products` table.. that's not the issue

Comment: Exclude the NULL records? Something like `Product.where(parent_product_id: 22033).where('products.product_description NOT NULL')....`

Comment: @engineersmnky yea I should have mentioned that as well. trying to do it without instantiating all the records.. to try and be as efficient as possible..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `length` function of your RDBMS to calculate the length, then order by it.

**Ties**

There might be many products with the same description length. In order to have consistent results, you will need a tie breaker as otherwise the order within the products with same description length is not defined. You could add an order by `id` clause.

**NULL**

Be aware that

```
select length(null)
```

will return `null` and not `0`.

`null` might be sorted before actual values or after (depending on your RDBMS and its config).

If you always need a numeric value you can do

```
select length(coalesce(null, ''))
```

which will return `0`.

`coalesce` returns the first `non-null` argument and therefore ensures that we always pass at least an empty string to `length`.

You can also use the `null last` option for the order clause.

You can also exclude records with a `null` value for the description:

```
products = Product.where.not(product_description: nil)
```

to avoid dealing with `null` values altogether.

If the column is not nullable, then there is no problem either.

Now if you just use this:

```rb
products = Product.all # or whatever conditions you need
products
  .order("length(coalesce(product_description, '')) desc")
  .order(id: :asc)
  .first
```

then Rails might complain (depends on the Version you are using) for security reasons with something like `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference: Dangerous query method`

which means you need to wrap the whole thing in `Arel.sql`

```rb
products = Product.all # or whatever conditions you need
products
  .order(Arel.sql("length(coalesce(product_description, '')) desc"))
  .order(id: :asc)
  .first
```

**Index**

If you have many records, you might want to add an index on the column length. See https://sqlfordevs.com/function-based-index for how to create a function based index.

Answer (score 2):

You can order by length and take first like this

```
Product
  .where(parent_product_id: 22033)
  .where.not(product_description: nil)
  .order("LENGTH(product_description) DESC")
  .first
```

`LENGTH` is RDBMS function and depends on specific system and may differ therefore

Comment: If you want to use it past Rails 5.2 you'll need the Arel.sql wrapper for the .order() like `.order(Arel.sql("LENGTH(product_description) DESC"))`